# How to exit While Loop if a non int value is entered?

Tags: java, while-loop

How can I make a while loop that will break if a non **int** value is entered?

So for example if a user enters a string, double or other primitive type other than an **int** the loop will exit.

Comment: entered "where"? Show us your code!

Comment: It depends on how the entry is done.  If you receive a String, you can (after trimming leading/trailing blanks) check that all remaining letters are in the set 01234356789.  A "." would indicate fraction (float) and any other character is a "string".

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class, and call [`hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29). If the method returns `false`, end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the user never enters a string, double or other; he enters some characters which `Scanner` reads and interprets, depending on what you asked it to do.

Two solutions:

```
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        scanner.nextInt();
    } catch (InputMismatchException ignored) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Well, `Scanner` is more "subtle" than that, but that's the meat of it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your input is and how you get it..

```
while(true)
{
  String myWord;
 //whatever way you are trying to get the input assume its in String myWord
  if(isNotInt(myWord))
     break;
}
```

Here is a helper method for a general `String`. you convert it to `int`, if the `string` is not a `int`, you will get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` exception and you can find out.

```
public static boolean isNotInt(String input) {
    boolean retVal = false
    try { 
        Integer.parseInt(input); 
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        retVal = true; 
    }
    return retVal;
}
```